# How to abort a FireStore transaction if any write operation fails?

Tags: node.js, firebase, transactions, google-cloud-firestore

In the code below, I am updating two documents in a transaction. However, if only one of the update succeeds and the other one fails for whatever reason, FireStore will complete the transaction anyways. How do I abort the transaction if any of the write operations fail?

```
var country; // forget to set a value to this variable
// Create a reference to the SF doc.
var sfDocRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");
var usaDocRef = db.collection("country").doc(country);  //country is undefined  
db.runTransaction(function(transaction) {
    return transaction.get(sfDocRef).then(function(sfDoc) {
        if (!sfDoc.exists) {
            throw "Document does not exist!";
        }

        var newPopulation = sfDoc.data().population + 1;
        if (newPopulation <= 1000000) {
            transaction.update(sfDocRef, { population: newPopulation }); //Will succeed
            transaction.update(usaDocRef, { lastPopulationUpdate: new Date()}); //Will fail
            return newPopulation;
        } else {
            return Promise.reject("Sorry! Population is too big.");
        }
    });
}).then(function(newPopulation) {
    console.log("Population increased to ", newPopulation);
}).catch(function(err) {
    // This will be an "population is too big" error.
    console.error(err);
});
```

In the above example, we forgot to assign a value to `country` .

Comment: Transactions are supposed to be [all-or-nothing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions).  There is no partial success.  How exactly are you observing this issue?

Comment: @DougStevenson I recreated the issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52457274/firestore-transaction-partial-success-issue Please check it out